# How can I get windows to remember my device after installing it so I don't get the new device message upon every connection?

Tags: windows, drivers

I have a piece of hardware that we created that connects to my PC via USB.  We also wrote the drivers for it.  EVERY time I plug this device in, the new device message comes up, even though the drivers are installed.  I can cancel the dialog and it works fine,  but it looks like crap and I'll be selling this product and want it to function like other USB products and only throw this dialog up once.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Please don't tell us what language you are using. We like guessing!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all of the USB device descriptor fields populated in your device?  Specifically, I am asking about the serial number field.

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/10/255047.aspx